# Spring boot batch - best method to filter large data

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing a spring boot batch application and I am confused about the best way to process big data. I have input file with millions of user ids and I need to remove those ids from another table. I dont think querying each userid a good idea but I dont have different solution at this time. Unfortunately these user ids are very random and wont be able to sort. Can any one suggest me the best approach? The database is Oracle.

Comment: Split the file into some specific size. Create a practitioner based on file size or type or your custom logic. Spring batch local partition thread pool configure based on your server power and configure chunk .  We have several jobs processing millions of data in spring batch in very few hours time and database is oracle. Let me know any code snippet is required

Comment: Thanks for the reply I really appreciate. I would like to know more on this. Did you mean running parallel jobs ? The main input file has just user ids and I want to query the other database to remove any ids which are not in my initial input file.  How do you query that ? The input file may contain more than 400 million ids and I need to filter out all other ids from second db to delete later.

Comment: Intuitively I'd say the general best method is to *not use Spring batch*. Instead load the data in the database and use a `not exists` query to filter the duplicated `ID`s. You may even perform it in one step using *external tables*. So if you insist to use *Spring* due to some policy, try to minimize the impact and let the database to do the hard work. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The data exists in the data base and all I have to do is to remove those ids which are not in the input file. Its a purge process. I cannot do much on database and all I can do is to it somehow figure out to do it programmatically from outside.

Comment: @Thomson my preference also to use "not exists" as this data is already available in database and operation is already in the DB server. Delete is always an expense operation even if oracle is so powerful. If your business  still not allowing direct operations on DB we can think of alternative.

Comment: @Rakesh; I do have millions of user ids in my input file which are very random. How you are suggesting to execute the "NOT EXIST" clause ?

Comment: Load this usedId to a table in database through SQLLDR. Write a PLSQL procedure that contains a for loop that will do delete by joining to loaded table. One point your are mentioning is not clear. Please explain "very random" scenario. Is this means  that id is coming dynamically in file and changing always.

Comment: The delete process is not streight forward. First I need to identify the ids and then send them to different team for review and once they return will start the delete process. So my all concern is identifying the ids. Let me know if you think anything other than creating table. Database interaction is limited to queries. By random I mean just random IDs it wont make any sense if not performing any sort based logic. Just trying to find the best way in case of performance and stability.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file in a temporary table then delete IDs that are not in it, something like:

```
DELETE FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMPORARY_TABLE).
```

This will perform better than doing a query for each ID in the file to check its existence and delete it if necessary.

If you really need to use Spring Batch for that, you can create a two steps job for this: the first step is chunk-oriented and loads the file in a temporary table, and the second step is a simple tasklet that executes the delete query. I would add a third step to remove the temporary table and clean-up things.